# Elastic Search must_not getting ignored

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query that to me seems to be ignoring the "must_not" part (using sense to test/debug)

```
POST /myserver.dev/indexedproduct/_search
{
      "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "isPublished": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "isProjectPublished": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "hidden": false
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "excludedMarkets": ["GI"]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "category": [
                        "headwear"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is returning 104 results.

If I run:

```
POST /myserver.dev/indexedproduct/_search
{
    "query": { 
        "bool": {
            "must_not": { "match": { "excludedMarkets":   "GI"}}
        }
    }
}
```

Then this returns 41 results.

I'd expect the first (not working one) to return 41 or less results due to the "must_not" clause.

I have looked at the ES documentation and my query looks correctly formed in terms of filtered queries and nested must/must_not statements.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT, test data, just 2 , one with the GI exludedMarkerts, and one without, meaning the end result should return just one,

```
"_index":"myindex.dev",
"_type":"indexedproduct",
"_id":"29426",
"_score":1,
"_source":{  
   "id":29426,
   "sku":"0123",
   "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ne.",
   "searchKeywords":[  
      "Lorem",
      "ipsum",
      "dolor"
   ],
   "productType":[  
      "Ipsum"
   ],
   "category":[  
      "Lorem"
   ],
   "colour":[  
      "Black/Black"
   ],
   "prices":{  
      "eur":35,
      "gbp":28
   },
   "catalogId":3,
   "ageRange":[  
      "adults"
   ],
   "brand":[  
      null
   ],
   "available":true,
   "bestSeller":false,
   "collections":[  
      "lorumipsum"
   ],
   "fit":[  
      "fitted"
   ],
   "newArrival":false,
   "style":[  
      "Lorum"
   ],
   "excludedMarkets":[  
      "BA",
      "GI",
      "MC",
      "MD",
      "SM",
      "AL"
   ],
   "isPublished":true,
   "isTranslated":false,
   "isProjectPublished":true,
   "hidden":false,
   "availableDate":"2015-09-17T01:00:00+01:00"
}
},
"_index":"myindex.dev",
"_type":"indexedproduct",
"_id":"2942",
"_score":1,
"_source":{  
   "id":2942,
   "sku":"012",
   "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ne.",
   "searchKeywords":[  
      "Lorem",
      "ipsum",
      "dolor"
   ],
   "productType":[  
      "IpsumLorem"
   ],
   "category":[  
      "IpsumLorem"
   ],
   "colour":[  
      "Black/Blue"
   ],
   "prices":{  
      "eur":35,
      "gbp":28
   },
   "catalogId":3,
   "ageRange":[  
      "adults"
   ],
   "brand":[  
      null
   ],
   "available":true,
   "bestSeller":false,
   "collections":[  
      "lorumipsum"
   ],
   "fit":[  
      "fitted"
   ],
   "newArrival":false,
   "style":[  
      "Lorum"
   ],
   "excludedMarkets":[  
      "BA",
      "MC",
      "MD",
      "SM",
      "AL"
   ],
   "isPublished":true,
   "isTranslated":false,
   "isProjectPublished":true,
   "hidden":false,
   "availableDate":"2015-09-17T01:00:00+01:00"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `must`/`must_not` and `should` clauses at the same level. This query should work:

```
POST /myserver.dev/indexedproduct/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "term": { "isPublished": true } },
            { "term": { "isProjectPublished": true } },
            { "term": { "hidden": false } }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            { "term": { "excludedMarkets": ["GI"] } }
          ],
          "should": [
            { "terms": { "category": ["headwear"] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for that, still bringing back to many (104 hits). Maybe I need to query and then query again, so the must_not is outside the filtered

Comment: @jj72uk Perhaps you should use `terms` instead of `term` in `must_not` clause?

Comment: I did attempt that as well prior to posting :)

Comment: @jj72uk Could you add some test data to your question? Would be easier to solve.

Comment: @jj72uk Looks like `should` filter is acting as `must` here. You probably have to run it as a query with constant_score.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work: Try this

```
    POST /myserver.dev/indexedproduct/_search
    {
        "query": {
         "filtered": {
           "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{"term": {"isPublished": true}},
                       {"term": {"isProjectPublished": true}},
                       {"term": {"hidden": false}},
                       {"bool": {
                          "must_not": [{"terms": {"excludedMarkets": ["GI"]}}]
                         }
                    },
                    {"bool": { "should": [{"terms": {"category": ["headwear"]}}]}}
             ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am using elasticsearch 2.1 and its giving me query_parsing_exception when i am using **term** instead of **terms**.

Comment: thats still bringing back 104 hits over <41 that I am expecting.

Comment: @jj72uk can you please edit your post and give an example or sample of your data?